# Copying profile overrides one-link limit in low-reputation profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, association

When I create a profile on one of the sites (SO/SU/SF), associate it with another and copy the profile details across, all links are copied.

However, I can't edit my profile until I reach 10 reputation or throw out all but one link because of the one-link limit for low-reputation accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are "trusted" enough on one site, I don't see a problem with copying the profile over (ie, if this is a bug report, it's one that probably would be "no fix").

If you are highly trusted on the original site, you'll get enough of a bonus to edit your profile with links intact (as Aether points out).

If you merely want to work around the limitation (which is a corner case and probably won't be fixed, even if it's determined to be unintended) then you can edit the profile fully on the original site, then copy it over again, then revert the original profile back.  This will allow you to have all the links you want with separate profiles on both sites.

Of course, the real solution is to gain rep on the secondary site so you gain those privileges naturally...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it ended as "no fix" since the situation is rather rare but it's an inconsistent behavior so I decided to file it.

Answer (score 3):

If your rep on one of the sites was high enough, you should get a +100 rep bonus on both sites, which will be enough to fully edit your profile. You need to associate from the account with the higher rep (minimum 200).

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

Comment: I had 25 reputation on an original site so haven't got bonus on target site.

Answer (score 2):

Links are now handled at the time of rendering depending on if you have enough reputation on that site or not, so copying no longer has an effect on this.  It was a change so that when you reach enough rep the links are automatically rendered as links, but has the side-effect of fixing this bug.